# (SQL) Getting a column for every ID out of a junction table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, junction-table

[If this was already answered elsewhere, I will thankfully take the link and delete this]

I have a playlists table:

```
pid | name 

1   | playlist 1 
2   | playlist 2
3   | playlist 3
```

and a songs table:

```
sid | name 

1   | song 1 
2   | song 2
3   | song 3
```

they are connection with this junction table:

```
pid | sid 

1   | 1 
1   | 2
1   | 3
2   | 2 
3   | 1
```

I already managed to get the join to work

```
SELECT      playlists.pid, songs.*
FROM        playlists
INNER JOIN  playlist_contains_song
ON          playlists.pid = playlist_contains_song.pid
INNER JOIN  songs
ON          playlist_contains_song.sid = songs.sid;
```

which gave me this result:

```
pid | sid | name 

1   | 1   | song 1    
1   | 2   | song 2
1   | 3   | song 3    
2   | 2   | song 2    
3   | 1   | song 1
```

Now I wondered if there's a way to get this data 'horizontally'.
The preferred output should look like this:

```
pid | 1 | 2 | 3

1   | 1 | 1 | 1
2   | 0 | 1 | 0
3   | 1 | 0 | 0
```

Where the columns are the sid's and the values stand for true or false, whether the song is part of the playlist or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT pid,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sid = 1) AS "1",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sid = 2) AS "2",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sid = 3) AS "3"
FROM playlist_contains_song
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY pid;
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get this done dynamically? In fact, there are thousands of songs - and if its possible, is this even recommended? Or should I use the table the join select gave me and do the rest in python/pandas?

Comment: Well you certainly could build the query string from Python (and it should be obvious how you would add, e.g., a column for the fourth song).  If you must do this from Postgres, then look into cross tab queries.